# Unity: Make the camera follow the player with a tag

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a game on which i added a character selection system, so for it to function i needed to add a "spawn point" on which the characters will spawn based on a prefab, but the code that i had wrote for the camera to follow the player won't work, so i was wondering if there is a way to make the camera follow an object or prefab via a tag. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using cinemachine?

Comment: No, im using unity as it comes when you download it

Comment: Try cinemachine, as it comes with a lot of features. It could help to solve this issue in 2 clicks.

Answer (score 0):

try with cinemachine

```
using Cinemachine;

public CinemachineVirtualCamera vcam;

private void Start()
{
   vcam.Follow = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").transform;
}
```

and simply drag & drop the camera Game Object onto the script.